# Rails: filter defined in lib file required in environment.rb disappears from filter_chain in production environment. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, filter, environment

In my rails application, I have a file in lib that, among other things, sets up a filter that runs on all controllers.

When running under development environment, everything runs fine. However, under production the filter goes missing. Funny thing is, by inspecting the `filter_chain`, I noticed other filters remain, eg. those defined in plugins, or later in the specific controller class.

I've tested this with both rails edge and v2.3.0.

#### Testing update:

I've now tested with older rails and found the issue to be present back to v2.1.0, but not in v2.0.5, I've bisect them and found the [986aec5](http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/986aec5dbbdfb578945e706cbe6a54c4f06640e5) rails commit to be guilty.

---

I've isolated the behavior to the following tiny test case:

```
# app/controllers/foo_controller.rb
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :text => 'not filtered'
  end
end

# lib/foobar.rb
ActionController::Base.class_eval do
  before_filter :foobar
  def foobar
    render :text => 'hi from foobar filter'
  end
end

# config/environment.rb (at end of file)
require 'foobar'
```

---

Here's the output I get when running under the **development** environment:

```
$ script/server &
$ curl localhost:3000/foo
> hi from foobar filter
```

And here's the output for the **production** environment:

```
$ script/server -e production &
$ curl localhost:3000/foo             
> not filtered
```

---

As alluded to before, it works fine for any environment when I do the same thing via plugin. All I need is to put what's under `lib/foobar.rb` in the plugin's `init.rb` file.

So in a way I already have a workaround, but I'd like to understand what's going on and what's causing the filter to go missing when in production.

I conjecture it's something in the different ways Rails handles loading in the different environments, but I need to dig deeper.

#### update

Indeed, I've now narrowed it down to the following config line:

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

If, in `production.rb`, `config.cache_classes` is changed from `true` to `false`, the test application works properly.

I still wonder why class reloading is causing such thing.

Comment: @kch -- What Rails version are you using?

Comment: updated the question with it: I've tested this with both rails edge and v2.3.0.

Comment: Huh, works for me in production and development on 2.2.2 (Sorry, I don't have a 2.3 install around here).  For kicks, I even confirmed it worked in 2.0.2.

Comment: @Pesto you mean you get "hi from foobar filter" in both cases? I have tested with 2.2.2 and I'm getting the error.

Comment: It does with with rails 2.0.5, but fails with 2.1.0. I'll try to bisect it to an specific commit.

Comment: Issue starts at rails commit 986aec5dbbdfb578945e706cbe6a54c4f06640e5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frederick Cheung on the [Rails list](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk?hl=en) had [the answer](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/msg/02ad57a81a89a120?hl=en):

> Because cache_classes does a little more than just that. The way 
>   before filters work, if Foo < Bar then only those filters defined in 
>   Bar at that point will be inherited by Foo - adding them to Bar at a 
>   later date will not do anythingn
>
> In development mode, the app starts, your file is required, the filter 
>   added to ActionController::Base. Later the first request comes along, 
>   the controller is loaded and it inherits that filter.
>
> When cache_classes is true then all of your application classes are 
>   loaded ahead of time. This happens before your file is required, so 
>   all of your controllers already exist when that file is run and so it 
>   has no effect. You could solve this by requiring this file from an 
>   initializer (ensuring it runs before app classes are loaded), but 
>   really why wouldn;t you just put this in application.rb ?
>
> Fred

---

My real case was actually way more involved, and this is the way I found to solve the issue:

```
config.after_initialize do
  require 'foobar'
end
```

The `after_initialize` block runs after the framework has been initialized but before it loads the application files, hence, it'll affect `ActionPack::Base` after it's been loaded, but before the application controllers are.

I guess that's the generally safe way to deal with all the preloading that goes on in production.

Answer (score 0):

Drop a ruby script in

> RAILS_ROOT\config\initializers

that contains

```
require "foobar.rb"
```

This invokes the before_filter for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I was really asking *why* it was happening. Workarounds I had a few.